# Hidden features of Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, preview, multi-touch

While using Safari, I accidentally three-finger tapped on a link and Preview of that web page popped up, like below. I think it's pretty useful.

[image]

Do you know any other hidden features of Safari?
I also, know that if you three-finger tapped in a word a dictionary definition pops up.

OSX 10.10.3 Safari 8.0.5

Comment: I might remember one. May I ask how you recorded this GIF?

Comment: Yeah sure, first I recored it with quicktime, and then I used an online converter from .mov to .gif. Then, I used an online gif compressor, because stack-exchange only allows you to upload up to 2MB.

Comment: Quicklook on links works system-wide in 10.10.3. Not only in Safari.

Comment: I've tried it with Chrome v. 42, and it doesn't work, for me it only works with Safari.

Comment: It's not really hidden feature it just got introduced in 10.10.3, and so did Spotlight Suggestion in the lookup. For e.g. if you look up (three finger click) an address it'll show the map. It's just like quick search, you eventually figure out these things.

Answer (score 1):

The same gesture, over any selected word [in most apps] will pop up a dictionary definition, with additional Spotlight options since Yosemite.

Keyboard equivalent is  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>D</kbd>

[image]